# Is it possible to write a DataTable that was created in memory to a database table

Tags: .net, datatable, ado.net

In .NET (an preferrably with C#), is it possible to create a `DataTable` in memory and *then* write it to a database.

All the example that I find seem to indicate that is only possible to write a `DataTable` back to a database from where its data was already selected.

Comment: I suppose that you are talking about the DataAdapter.Update method right? And the exact table already exists on the database schema?

Comment: It's definitely not clear if the DataTable exists in the Database or not.

Comment: Yes, I am referrung to the `Update` method. I hoped it was possible to create the table and insert data into it, but I could create the table if necessary.

Comment: A DataTable is not directly connected to a database. You can call Update on a DataAdapter that is connected to different database than the one you selected from.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you mean by "write it to a database."? Do you mean updating / adding data to an existing table, or do you mean creating a new table on the database? Are you asking for a specific database (and if so, what database?) or do you mean in general?

Comment: By *writing into a database* I meant to (ideally) create a table and then fill it with the data from the datatable. With database, I was referring to any database that I can connect to with ADO.NET. If the automatic creation of the table is not possible, I could create it also differently.

Comment: Different databases supports different syntax. In SQL Server, you could use a user defined table type and a table valued parameter to do a `select into` query, which will create a new table with the columns and data of the data table. I think MySql supports `create table as select...` (perhaps that was Oracle, maybe both of them?) I don't know about other databases - I'm working with SQL Server and it's been a long time since I've last had to use other databases.

Comment: @Zohar this assumes that the data that is filled into the new table already is somewhere in the target database. In my case, the data is in another database.

Comment: So you basically want to write an import/export process in c#?